# NitrousIo Mac app won't connect/sync to box

Tags: nitrousio

My friend created a box where we are collaborating on a project. I downloaded the nitrous IO mac app but it won't connect/sync to his box.

Similarly, I can't find any option in preferences that would allow me to do this.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac App doesn't sync boxes which you are collaborating just yet (as of version 0.1.7), but this feature will be available soon!